# How to find $R$ as a set of ordered pairs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose I am given a set $A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and a relation $R$ on $A$ which is given by $x R y \iff y=2x+3.$

In order to write $R,$ how would I go answering this question? Would I just input all the values of the set $A$ as $x$ giving me $\{(0,3),(1,5),(2,7),(3,9),(4,11),(5,13),(6,15),(7,17),(8,19),(9,21)\}?$ Or perhaps do I only input numbers in $y=2x+3$ that would output numbers only between $0-9?$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhalps would it be {(0,3),(1,5),(2,7),(3,9)}?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the following set

$$A = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$

and $R$ the relation on $A$ given by the following condition

$$xRy \iff y = 2x+3.$$

What you are trying to determine is the relation $R$ itself (by defining it in extension). I.e., the relation $R$ will be

$$R = \{(x,y) \in A \times A \mid y = 2x + 3\}.$$

Now, doing the arithmetic, you observe that

$$\begin{align}
3 = 2 \cdot 0 +3 && \implies (0,3) \in R\\
5 = 2 \cdot 1 +3 && \implies (1,5) \in R\\
7 = 2 \cdot 2 +3 && \implies (2,7) \in R\\
9 = 2 \cdot 3 +3 && \implies (3,9) \in R
\end{align}$$

and also that

$$\begin{align}\forall x \in A, x \geq 4 & \implies y \geq 11\\
& \implies y \notin A\\
& \implies (x,y) \notin R.\end{align}$$

This means that there is no more ordered pairs of $A \times A$ that belong to R.

Therefore

$$R = \{(0,3),(1,5),(2,7),(3,9)\}.$$